# Omega 4 and 2 problems

Tags: drupal-7, responsive-design, themes

I'm new in omega 4 and i got problems or it's maybe missunderstanding .
How can i define 960px in omega 4 ?
should i define it in `_grid.scss` like this :

```
$grid: 12px ;
$gutters: 1/3;

$tab:44em;
$desk:77em;
$mobile:15em 35em;
```

If it's true , how can i have something like omega 3 zone-wrapper with 100 % width ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are requesting, you can use the following css in your css template file:

```
.l-page{width:960px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

But then it won't be responsive, though.